# CodeFirst EF 4.1 Inheritance - Renaming PK/FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have two classes, ThreadItem and Enquiry.

```
public class ThreadItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
} 

public class ThreadItemMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ThreadItem>
{
    public ThreadItemMapping()
    {
        Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("ThreadItemId");
    }
}

[Table("Enquiry")]
public class Enquiry : ThreadItem
{
    public string Comment { get; set;}
}
```

Now, this works, not a single problem. I have a [ThreadItem] table, and an [Enquiry] table. My Enquiry table has a PK/FK which is mapped to ThreadItem, which is what I need. However, I would like to rename the column.

Currently is it [ThreadItemId], as per the ThreadItemMapping class. I Would like to re-name it [EnquiryId]. I understand that it being called [ThreadItemId] makes sense, this is more of a 'is it possible' question to be honest.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
D

Comment: Interesting question! EF 4.0 actually supports mapping an arbitrary column name to the key property of the base class in Table-Per-Type inheritance. (You can even map this in the designer.) But it looks that the DbContext API has no option to configure this scenario. Key column names must be identical in base and all derived classes. As far as I can see at least...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

I'm not saying it cannot be done, but these examples don't show such a thing being done.

If you use Fluent-API conventions, however, it's quite simple.

Your POCO definitions:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Data {get; set;}
}
```

Configuring the mappings to the DB:

```
public class BaseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseClass>
{
    public BaseConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(k => k.Id);
    Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
}
}

public class DerivedConfiguration : BaseConfiguration
{
    public DerivedConfiguration()
{
    Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("BaseClassId");
}
}
```

putting it all together

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
}

public DbSet<BaseClass> Bases { get; set; }
public DbSet<DerivedClass> Deriveds { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BaseConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DerivedConfiguration());
}
}
```

So you instantiate a MyContext passing in your connection string and the configurations tell EF how to relate to the tables.

Comment: Hmmm, not quite what i want, i want to rename the column for the Enquiry table only, there will be more classes than inherit from ThreadItem.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I hit the wrong table - but the principle is the same.

Comment: Hmm.  You know I'm better at this with configurations.  In a configuration file setup (which I believe is more robust) you would use Property(p => ThreadItemId = p.Id); to override the column name.

Comment: Hmmm, i'm confused. That Property(p => ThreadItemId = p.Id); doesn't make sense to me, or VS, Assignment isn't valid and surely == will just be a comparison operator.

Comment: The Property configuration is valid.  The EntityTypeConfiguration class magically understands it that the BaseClassId identifies the name of the column in which Id will be stored.    This article may help explain it better - note however that the article is doing all the configurations in OnModelBuilding, where my example is using Configuration entities.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx

Comment: But surely, BaseClassId would have to be defined as a property, otherwise it doesn't exist anywhere. I've taken your sample and tried to make it work, with no success, i must be missing something. http://pastebin.com/TmCxMaPr

Comment: It exists in the database.  Give me a bit and I'll provide a more comprehensive example.

Comment: It does indeed, but Visual Studio at compile time has no idea about that. Very interested to see your example, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, silly me, I fell back on a CTP release syntax.  Sorry about that.  The EF 4.1 syntax is somewhat more clear - it's Property(p=>p.Id).HasColumnName("BaseClassId");

Comment: :) Heh, that would have made sense had I of ever used the CTP's. I had tried the HasColumnName approach, however it complains then because the Property is not declared in Enquiry, it's declared in ThreadItem. Really starting to lean towards this not being possible :-)

Comment: Nah, it's perfectly possible - we're doing it in production here.  I just suck at writing this out from memory. :) You'll need references to System.Data.Entity, System.Data.Entity.Design, System.Data.DataSetExtensions and EntityFramework

Comment: Anyway I've revised my example to be hopefully clearer (and more accurate)

Comment: Thanks, that does make more sense, however I still think I am missing something. Because DerivedConfiguration inherits from BaseConfiguration, I can't add both configs. So i now end up with just a [BaseClasses] table, which isn't what i'm after. If i add ToTable("Base") & ToTable("Derived") to the relevant configs, then i only end up with a Derived table, and no Base Table. This is very confusing :-)

Comment: This may give you a better example.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx

Comment: Hmmm, that did clear it up a little, however still unable to see how i can set the column name on the Derived Table. Surely it can't be possible... or very well hidden!             modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>()
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("BaseTable"))
                .Map<DerivedClass>(f =>
                {
                    f.MapInheritedProperties();
                    f.ToTable("Derived");

                }).Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("BaseItemId");

Comment: Thanks for your help Greebo, have come to the conclusion it's not possible after talking to a few more people. Thanks for all your help, really appreciated.